# Get authdata of a user through rest api of parse.com

Tags: api, rest, parse-platform

I'm having trouble finding out a user's authdata information (facebook id or twitter screenname) using REST API of parse.com

I have the objectId of the user:
-I queried the user class, this information is hidden.
-I tried with my master key and I get no response.

Any ideas?

More investigation reveals a real strange behaviour:
chrome won't run my query to *users/objectId* complaining:
**"Request header field X-Parse-Master-Key is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers"**

but when I go to the URL directly from chrome and enter username:password as applicationid:masterkey it gives me the full user info!